# How to resolve eth-utils and eth-tester installation issues?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

While installing the web3.py I am getting the following error message.
I am new to blockchain development. Can Someone help me to resolve this Error?

Error:

[image]

Comment: Curious why opt for an image when we are asked to share all [code, data and error tracebacks as **text, not images**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below set of commands resolved all the ERRORs.

```
pip3 install eth-hash
pip3 install eth-abi
pip3 install eth-account
pip3 install eth-keys
pip3 install eth-utils
pip3 install rlp
```

Answer (score 1):

sidenote: in future, to resolve conflicting package dependencies e.g if you get an error like so:

```
The user requested eth-utils eth-abi 2.2.0 depends on eth-utils<2.0.0 and >=1.2.0 eth-keys 0.4.0 depends on eth-utils<3.0.0 and >=2.0.0
```

it is clear that one package needs eth-utils<2 and the other needs eth-utils>2, so there is no in between

what you need to simply do is actually go to eth-abi and eth-keys and completely unspecify the version of the two to be installed, pip will find the best versions that satisfy  both without errors, this is the fastest way to solve this dependency issue